# Persistent pyvirtualdisplay

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pyvirtualdisplay

I am trying to create a virtual display to crawl through web pages using selenium webdrivers. My code is something like

```
    display = Display(visible = 0, size = (800,800))
    display.start()

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

But this display is not persistent or accessible from other instances of other programs. can anybody please help and tell how to create a virtual display using pvirtualdisplay library so that i am able to use it for any other process while it is alive?

Comment: As long as you have an Xvfb session, you can use the display. There shouldn't be an issue. Can you put in more details to debug.